# unable to add server.xml on tomcat8 dockerfile. error in xml

Tags: xml, docker, utf-8, dockerfile, tomcat8

Ok I´m quite lost over here and tried many things unable to solve problem. this is the situation.
I´m building a tomcat 8 official image with a dockerfile. the thing is under this image te server.xml file points to port 8080 and I would like to point to port 443. So I enter the container. cat the /conf/server.xml file, copy the content to a local editor (sublime, notepad ++ or visual studio code) change the part 8080 by 443 and also added certificates like this. the rest of the xml files remains the same

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           SSLCertificateFile="conf/star.grey.com.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/server.key"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional"
           SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Then I saved the file localy on my editor as server.xml and add this file on same destination of dockerfile in which I add the line:
 ADD server.xml /conf/server.xml  (which overwrites the existing one)

So I have 2 new images alpine:tomcat8 and alpine:tomcat8-with-new-serverxml

I if run a container with the oficial image without any modification, it runs successfully. If i Run a container with the modified image i get now:

```
-Aug-2018 14:28:56.303 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse Fatal Error at line 1 column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.


org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

Is the same exact xml that I copied from container from /conf/server.xml. I just modified 443 port and added the certificates.

how come same file now is unrecognized? I tried:

copyng the container content of server.xml in a new file locally, modified the 443 part. save as server.xml with utf-8 ANSI, utf-8 or NO BOM in notepadd ++ , sublime or visual stuio code. And every time I upload the file to the image and container starts I get same issue.
How can I solve this? it´s driving me crazy.

I tried the option of entering the container modifying the file and commitin change to new image and this works, but this doesn´t help, since this image is build during a pipeline with jenkins, i can´t login in container during the jenkins pipeline.

PLEASE HELP

thank you

this is what is original on server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

this is what I would like to chang it for:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           SSLCertificateFile="conf/star.grey.com.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="conf/server.key"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional"
           SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

Also I use the cat -A in server.xml on docker container that is working ok and file  saw some "$" characters  in some parts. Should I remove them manually? However why If copied from original and they already have those "$" when I edit that file and add it again it give the error that I´m getting? quite conffuging . check image of some part of the  original web.xml in container that is running.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a shell in your new created container and try to cat the server.xml file? Use `cat -A` to show all the hidden characters.

That error is caused probably by a non-existent file or a character before the beginning of the xml content.

Also, if the only thing you're doing is changing the tomcat's port you have other solutions:

- Expose the port you want when you run the container: `-p 443:8080`
- Mount the server.xml with your configuration when running the container as a volume `-v ./server.xml:/conf/server.xml`
- Or if you want to really build your image and change just the port you can do `RUN value=`cat conf/server.xml`&& echo "${value//8080/443}" >| conf/server.xml`

Comment: this is a jenkinspipeline so the image is build on a jenkinsfile calling a dockerfile later for building and pushing the image to azure registry. Later the pipeline uses this comand to build a container inside the job:
sh "az container create --resource-group rg --name ${containerName} --image image-in-registry --cpu 1 --memory 1.5 --registry-username ${spn_uname} --registry-password ${spn_pw} --ip-address public --ports 80 --dns-name-label gp-search-prod2"  So azure only expose the number you said on --port. 
this container won´t be having a -v usage. It all has to be on the dockerfile

Comment: Also I updated the original config file and the one I should Have instead, check last updated code.Is not only changing 8080 for 443.

Comment: and  also did the cat -A command as you suggested.Also updated

Comment: Are you sure `value=cat conf/server.xml && echo "${value//8080/443}"` will output the contents op file `conf/server.xml` with the string "8080" replaced by "443"?